# SAS: How to Prevent ABORT on Error

Tags: error-handling, sas

I have an expected error with `&syserr.` of `1020`.  When the error is encountered, the program terminates with the following message:

```
FATAL: Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.
       Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.
```

I know what the problem is and there is no solution for it.  However, since I know what causes the problem, I want to alert the user of how to fix it before the program terminates.

That is, between when the error occurs and when the program is aborted, I want to execute some code.

I've scoured the internet and could not find anything which said this couldn't be done.  In fact, many answers on SO implied it could be done.  But I have no idea how.

Comment: How are you running the program?  Interactive?  Batch?

Comment: I guess technically interactive.  I am in the SAS Windowing Environment, using the Enhanced Editor.  I select the statements I wish to execute and then I press "Submit".  The code which produces the error exists in a macro.

Comment: When you say "aborted", then, do you just mean that the data step terminates?  Or does SAS end?  Or the macro terminate abnormaly?

Comment: The code stops executing and control is returned to the Enhanced Editor.  An ERROR message is written to the log.  Ideally, I would like to execute code between the error occurring and the ERROR message being written.  I know SAS doesn't have a try/catch construct, so I'm hoping there may be an "on error goto" type mechanism.  http://www.antonis.de/qbebooks/gwbasman/onerror.html

Comment: After this happens is you submit another little DATA step will it work?  Or is your entire interactive session pretty much broken and you need to close SAS and restart?

Comment: The session is still intact and I may submit other steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know &syserr is being set, one option would be to write your own %OnError macro, something like:

```
%macro OnError(debug=0);
  %if &syserr ne 0 %then %do;
    %*blah blah blah;
  %end;
%mend OnError;
```

So your code looks like:

```
data want;
  set have;
  oops;
run;
%OnError()
```

Note that &syserr is reset after each step boundary, so you need to test it immediately after the suspect step.  There are other macro vars with return codes that persist.

If the error was bad enough for SAS to enter syntaxcheck mode (set obs=0 and noreplace), you would have to do more to recover.  But I think that is off by default in interactive SAS.

Comment: I think that if this were a normal error this would be exactly right.  I think though that the error he's referring to doesn't follow those lines - it's more of an error in the SAS code supervisor or whatever, where it overloads.  Not sure though.

Comment: This allows me to execute code, although I cannot find a way to prevent the abort.  For instance, I can write a message to log which better details why the program aborts.  I do not seem to be able to prevent the abort from happening.

Comment: Agree, it won't avoid the abort or the error message. It could be used to "recover" in the sense of retry the step (if it was a network issue or similar) or run an alternative step, or email somebody, etc.  But it's not like having a true try...catch.  I think your stuck either trying to avoid the error or recover after the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's clunky, the desired result can be achieved using the [%LABEL](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/67912/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p024o0rob0gt0wn1dy84nzqfbz0h.htm) and [%GOTO](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/67912/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0jfeh75p72icen1ddd9una5zbmm.htm) statements.

It must be observed that

> "the label that is the target of the %GOTO statement must exist in the
>   current macro; you cannot branch to a label in another macro with a
>   %GOTO statement."

Since the error is occurring within code already in a macro, a separate macro cannot be used to handle the error event.  (SAS advises not to create macros inside of other macros).

Comment: Good catch.  I couldn't come up with an example that emulates my problem, so I removed the example you are referring to.  Your answer, along with %goto/%label, should hopefully provide sufficient information for prosperity.